# How to concat substrings with regexp_matches (as analogy regexp_substr in teradata) in Postgres 9.4

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am having migration from teradata to greenplum and there is a string concatenation with regex_substr which is not existing at Postgres 9.4 version.

The part of the existing code is:

`TRIM(COALESCE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Office №9013/0713', '(?<=№)[0-9]+', 1,1,'i), '-1')(INT))||'_'||TRIM(COALESCE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Office №9013/0713', '(?<=/)[0-9]+', 1,1,'i), '-1')(INT))`

Results is follwing:
`9013_713`

I have tried using `regexp_matches` function as I checked lookbehind is not existing in 9.4.

Not sure if lookbehind `'(?:№)([0-9]+)'` is correct for 9.4.

`regexp_matches('Office №9013/0713', '(?:№)([0-9]+)', 'gi')` first part extraction after №.

`regexp_matches('Office №9013/0713', '(?:\/)([0-9]+)', 'gi')` for second part extraction after /.

The problem is that the result above provides array and I cannot concat to single string. Is there any easy approach to achieve `9013_713` with simple structure?

Comment: If you know there is only one match, you can wrap each `REGEXP_MATCHES` with `array_to_string(REGEXP_MATCHES(...), '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a *single* match returned (which is what `regexp_substr()` is typically doing), using `substring(... from ...)` is easier than `regexp_matches()` which returns multiple rows of arrays.

```
substring('Office №9013/0713' from '№([0-9]+/[0-9]+)')
```

returns `9013/0713`

---

To concatenate the results as integers, you can use two `substring()` calls

```
concat(
  substring('Office №9013/0713' from '№([0-9]+)/[0-9]+')::int,
  '_',
  substring('Office №9013/0713' from '№[0-9]+/([0-9]+)')::int
);
```

Note the different use of groups in the two `substring()` calls. Casting the result to an integer will drop leading zeros.

This will fail if the regex doesn't find any match and returns an empty string!

Comment: thats perfect, but i need to drop leading zeros so results are 9013_713. I use cast(substring() as int) || '_' || cast(substring() as int) which leads to 9013_713